# Google Ads API - Which metrics can I use to get the number of clicks of a Campaign per day

Tags: google-ads-api

I am looking for a way to get number of clicks per day between START_DATE and END_DATE. The documentation for Google ADS v10 is huge and so far I'm unable to get clicks per day.

NOTE: I'm able to get total number of clicks BETWEEN DATES but I need clicks / day. Could anyone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is `segments.date` in your select clause. I would expect your query to look something like this.

```
SELECT 
    campagin.name
    , metrics.clicks
    , segments.date 
FROM campaign 
WHERE 
    segments.date >= '2022-06-01'
```

This link is the google query builder helper and it will probably help you out if you get stuck.

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v11/campaign_query_builder

Comment: Thank you for your response @James Waring. I would like to share that the above G.A.Q.L. returns a total number of clicks from last 30 days but instead what I need is to display clicks per day. Meaning for example I need to display number of clicks on 1st of June, then 2nd of June then 3rd of June and so on till last 30 days.

Comment: The only other thing to try is maybe putting a date. I have updated my example for you. If it still does the same i can't see why it wouldn't be working for you as I use the same query and get the data by day.

Comment: Alright. I understand what you are saying. Let me implement this as well. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Thank you for your response @James Waring. The G.A.Q.L. that you have provided started working for me now.